# Как записать отдельный элемент массива в отдельный textbox?

Tags: c#, массивы

Пользователь вводит размерность двумерного массива - создается нужный массив из textboxs-ов. Как записать отдельный элемент массива в отдельный текст бокс?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int[,] matrix = new int[n, n];
TextBox[,] t = new TextBox[n, n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // проходим по элементам масива
    {
        matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(20);

        t[i, j] = new TextBox(); // для каждого элемента массива создаем текстбокс
        t[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 70 + 20, j * 20 + 20); // привязываем расположение тексбоксов к индексам масива, чтоб они не налаживались друг на друга
        t[i, j].Size = new Size(70, 20); // размеры текстбокса

        panel1.Controls.Add(t[i, j]); // добавляем текстбоксы на панель

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все, додумалась

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        matrix[k, l] = rnd.Next(20);

        t[i, j].Text = Convert.ToString(matrix[k, l]);
    }
```